# jQuery firing only on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, flexslider, woothemes

Working on a slider for a site. Using the Flexslider provided by woo themes. I'm having trouble getting the slider to load and work properly. As of right now on initial page load the images in the slider are displayed in li order. I have to refresh the page for the slides to hide and the slider to work.

My current script:

placed in the body just above the slider –

```
$(window).load(function() {
              $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide"
              });
            });
```

and placed in my footer at bottom of page –

```
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

I've done quite a bit of searching for a solution to this across similar topics here on the site and can't seem to get a solution that solves my issue. I've replaced my `$(window).load(function() {` with `$(document).ready()` but still had no luck.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: What happens if you remove the first snippet? It appears that you are initializing the slider twice.

Comment: @j08691 Not sure how to recreate the issue on a jsfiddle. If I test the slider entirely on it's own I don't seem to have any issues. As soon as I place the slider into a page I have to refresh that page for it to work properly.

Comment: @MasterAM Initially I thought the same thing. I removed the first snippet and still had the problem. Replaced the first snippet and removed the second and no luck there either.

Comment: Well, I guess that there is another problem somewhere, but I would still remove one of them to begin with and would probably trigger it on DOM ready. I don't suppose that you have a live link... What does the network tab and the error console of you favorite browser's dev tools say?

Comment: @MasterAM I do have a live link [link](http://bit.ly/19aWLcq) With the error console in Safari, I don't see any errors pointing or relating to the slider.

Comment: @EricH, it works for me on the first pageload in Chrome. There is a "flash of unstyled content" in the slideshow on Firefox (which should probably be resolved by creating the slideshow onDomReady), but it is only momentary and the slideshow appears to be OK. The only thing that I am getting is a 404 error on an external image.

Comment: @MasterAM Ah I just noticed that on a direct entrance to the 'company' page where the slider is there doesn't seem to be any issues. However, if you enter the site from any other page or you leave the slider page and return to it from it's navigation link, the problem occurs having to refresh.

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with the code in `/wp-content/themes/pal/js/init.js`, as the `ajaxComplete` handler attempts to push the current URL into an array called `_gaq`, which does not exist. This is most likely Google tracking code, so you should probably include Google Analytics or change this code. Not sure that it is related to the error in your question, though.

Comment: @MasterAM I noticed that in the error console as well. I'll have to keep trying to troubleshoot this or find an alternative. I've tried a few different responsive sliders now and all have had the same issue. Thanks for the assistance! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Eric, why is this tagged with Mootools?

Comment: @Sergio my apologies. I meant to tag as woo themes. I'll edit that now.

Comment: No problem. Good that you will fix it. Cheers!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your problem? or do you have a live link to your problem?

Comment: @Sergio there is a link a few comments up to the direct page where the slider is. I'm not getting the issue on a direct entrance to the site's 'company' page where the slider is located but only when entering the 'company' page from another page on the site or leaving the 'company' page and reentering. Here is a link to the [site](http://bit.ly/1ah4hqM)

Comment: Eric, what is this script? It throws an error. Can be a scope problem. (last script on the company page). Can you try without it `<script src="http://www.palomaspices.com/wp-content/themes/pal/js/init.js"></script>`

Comment: @Sergio Without that script the pages don't show. I just removed it and had to replace it because all pages went blank.

Comment: I will go sleep now, but that file complains on console that `_gaq` is undefined. Just on the first page load...

Comment: @Sergio Thanks! Will look into that right now. Fingers crossed. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Fixed the _gaq error but still having issues with the slider..

Comment: Eric, the slideshow works in company now at first load! Did you get it working?

Comment: @Sergio No. Still having the same issue with it not firing on first load. The slider will actually work on first load if you enter the site directly on the company page. If you leave the company page and re-enter from the navigation links, the slider is broken. If you enter the site from it's home page or any other page and navigate to the company page, it's broken. I did manage to take care of the undefined _gaq error though.

Comment: I think company page is not loaded as a new page, but instead the content is loaded by script. That makes the slideshow not work. Find the script that loads the new content and add the caller for the slidesho after the append/html insert.

Comment: @Sergio I think I lost you here.. My Javascript knowledge is still pretty limited.. I'm sure this would be done on the .init file just not exactly sure where or how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your init.js is loading page content and updating the url to look like it's a new page. When the content of a new page is inserted I don't find anywhere that the slide code is re-attached/re-started. So try to add this part in your code (init.js). It worked for me testing on your site with console.

Find this code/function and add as suggested.

```
$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(w, v, u) {
    mypath = u.url;
    mypath = mypath.replace("http://www.palomaspices.com/", "");
    mypath = mypath.replace("http://palomaspices.com/", "");
    mypath = mypath.replace("http://palomaspices.com/", "palomaspices.com");

//Start of new code
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        start: function(slider) {
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
/end of new code

    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", mypath])
});
```

Comment: Perfect! After your suggestion my initial attempt to insert the slideshow was placed in a different section of the .init file which in turn resulted in the same issue where the slider wasn't loading properly. After your example clarifying the placement on the code the slider works perfectly and loads correctly every time. Definitely appreciate all the help on this!

Comment: @EricH you are welcome :) I just noticed your question because you tagged mootools, so nice mistaque :)